# Can't install ruby on rails in MobaXTerm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't install ruby on rails using the MobaXTerm application.

I execute `gem install rails` and I get this output:

```
Fetching: rack-1.6.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-1.6.0
Fetching: rack-test-0.6.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rack-test-0.6.3
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.2
with the following patches applied:
        - 0001-Revert-Missing-initialization-for-the-catalog-module.patch
        - 0002-Fix-missing-entities-after-CVE-2014-3660-fix.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.2.tar.gz into tmp/i686-pc-cygwin/ports/libxml2/2.9.2... ERROR
sh: zxf: command not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --help
        --clean
        --use-system-libraries
        --enable-static
        --disable-static
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --enable-cross-build
        --disable-cross-build
/home/mobaxterm/.gem/ruby/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:262:in `extract_file': Failed to complete extract task (RuntimeError)
        from /home/mobaxterm/.gem/ruby/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:35:in `block in extract'
        from /home/mobaxterm/.gem/ruby/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:33:in `each'
        from /home/mobaxterm/.gem/ruby/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:33:in `extract'
        from /home/mobaxterm/.gem/ruby/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:107:in `cook'
        from extconf.rb:278:in `block in process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:177:in `tap'
        from extconf.rb:177:in `process_recipe'
        from extconf.rb:475:in `<main>'
```

I have installed the plugins for ruby, sqlite and for gcc. Except for that the application has been just installed.

Versions are:

Ruby: ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [i386-cygwin]
 Gem: 2.0.3

Hopefully, somebody has found how to get this work.

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to install Ruby-on-rails on MobaXterm, you can simply type the following command in MobaXterm terminal:

```
apt-get install ruby-rails
```

This will download and install the ruby-rails package and all the needed dependancies.

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue. You must install tar

```
apt-get install tar
```